# Suppress specific appointments

Tags: crystal-reports-xi, suppress

I want to suppress appointments that have been cancelled so that they are not visible to the patient. 
The appointments are identified as cancelled by {schedule.status} = X in the DB.
If I use the group selection formula to suppress this field, all it does is omit the X but still returns the rest of the appointment/time/date etc.

I have tried other methods of suppression, some resulting in a far heavier suppression of other appointments that I do not want excluded!

I have also tried the NOT({schedule.status} IN ["X"]) method but this has not worked.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't require then don't take at all in the report....

write your formula in `Record Selection Formula`

```
NOT({schedule.status} IN ["X"])
```

If you write above in record selection then the cancelled appointments won't be inculded in report.